# Match nodes based on attribute refernce with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

given the following XML snippet:

```
<TypeB id="FD2020Q1YTD">
  <identifier>num1</identifier>
</TypeB>

<TypeA ref="FD2020Q1YTD">num1</TypeA>
<TypeA ref="FD2020Q1YTD_dei_LegalEntityAxis_pnw_ArizonaPublicServiceCompanyMember">num2</TypeA>
```

How can I query using XPath the following:
I want to select all "TypeA" elements, where element's ref attribute points such a node where intensifier's inner text matchs to TypeA's inner text.

"num1" in "TypeA" should match to "num1" in "TypeB/identifier"

**Update:**

wp78de's suggestion seems to be the best:

```
//TypeA[.=//TypeB/identifier and @ref=//TypeB/@id]
```

but in this case, how can decide, that the first condition: `.=//TypeB/identifier` refers to the same TypeB instance, as the second condition: `@ref=//TypeB/@id`

Comment: Was any answer helpful to you? Consider accepting/voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
//TypeA[.=//TypeB/identifier and @ref=//TypeB/@id]
```

[Demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3CTypeB%20id%3D%22XD2020Q1YTD%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cidentifier%3Enum1%3C%2Fidentifier%3E%0A%3C%2FTypeB%3E%0A%0A%3CTypeB%20id%3D%22FD2020Q1YTD%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cidentifier%3Enum1%3C%2Fidentifier%3E%0A%3C%2FTypeB%3E%0A%0A%3CTypeA%20ref%3D%22XD2020Q1YTD%22%3Enum0%3C%2FTypeA%3E%0A%3CTypeA%20ref%3D%22FD2020Q1YTD%22%3Enum1%3C%2FTypeA%3E%0A%3CTypeA%20ref%3D%22FD2020Q1YTD_dei_LegalEntityAxis_pnw_ArizonaPublicServiceCompanyMember%22%3Enum2%3C%2FTypeA%3E&=&extract=%2F%2FTypeA%5B.%3D%2F%2FTypeB%2Fidentifier%20and%20%40ref%3D%2F%2FTypeB%2F%40id%5D&=%2F%2FTypeA%5B.%3D%2F%2FTypeB%2Fidentifier%20and%20%40ref%3D%2F%2FTypeB%2F%40id%5D&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=xml&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
//TypeA[text()=//TypeB/identifier/text()]
```

Output should be:

```
<TypeA ref="FD2020Q1YTD">num1</TypeA>
```

Comment: It seems to works, but I think, there is a logical error in it.
In the real XML multiple TypeB element can contain similar text, so I'm looking to a solution that will check that the ref attribute of the TypeA node refer to a TypeB instance, where its child instance's text's contains text "num1"

Comment: @moravas First, if the xml in your question doesn't represent the "real xml", please edit your question and make sure that it does. I can only work with what I see. Second, your expectation described in the comment is not the same as in the question, so I have no idea what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using XPath 2.0:

```
for $a in //TypeA, $b in //TypeB
    return if ($b/@id=$a/@ref and $a/text()=$b/identifier/text()) then $a else ()
```

Don't think that it's possible to solve with XPath 1.0.